# Правильное ударение в прилагательном "непролитый"

Tags: орфоэпия, поэзия

Как правильно поставить ударение: "непролИтые слезы" или " непрОлитые слезы"?
Текст поэтический, допустим ли в стихах перенос ударения?

Answer (score 2):

М. Баронова. [**Русский язык. ЕГЭ-учебник**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=nQDMAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA14&lpg=PA14&dq=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&source=bl&ots=aPmzpJfaKP&sig=V7-gZ3hsM4sx7L4H-KadDfMNW18&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYv8mf9a3aAhXMYVAKHcOvDq04ChDoAQhAMAY#v=onepage&q=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&f=false):
страдательные причастия от глаголов **лить, пить** отличаются вариативным ударением (прол**и**тый — пр**о**литый, прол**и**т — пр**о**лит, прол**и**то — пр**о**лито, но: пролит**а**).

[**Словарь трудностей произношения и ударения в современном русском языке**](https://diffc_ru.academic.ru/6746/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9):
**ПРОЛИТЫЙ**
пр**о**литый и прол**и**тый, *прич., кратк. ф.* пр**о**лит (допустимо прол**и**т), пролит**а** (допустимо пр**о**лита, не рекомендуется прол**и**та), пр**о**лито, пр**о**литы (допустимо прол**и**то, прол**и**ты).

Отрицательная частица на ударение не влияет, поэтому Вы вольны выбрать любой вариант, подходящий по рифме, — это не будет ошибкой (ни в стихах, ни в обычном тексте).

*...Ласка нежданная, утоляющая

Неутолимую боль,

Шелест, дыханье, память страдающая,

Слез непрол**и**тых соль –

Всю я тебя люблю...*
З. Гиппиус. Вся

*Тот возраст, который с собою принес

Утраты, прощанья, наверное, он-то

И застил туманом непр**о**литых слез

Прямую и резкую грань горизонта.*
М. Петровых. Черта горизонта

Answer (score 1):

Оба варианта возможны, сравнить:

Возвысила ночь свою черную голову, Созвездьями смотрит на море и сушу, И, в волны **пролИтому,** яркому олову Вверяю ночную, бездомную душу (В Брюсов)

Победный лавр, и скиптр вселенной, И ратей **прОлитую** кровь Ты бросил на весы, надменный, — И перевесила любовь! (В. Брюсов).

Вариантное ударение в глаголе ***прОлил и пролИл*** сохраняется и в причастии: **прОлитый и пролИтый**.